# Property set in constructor overrides property on prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

Trying to clear up some prototypal inheritances basics.

```
function thirdSampleObject(){
  this.first_var = 3;
  this.update = function(){"Hi I am a function"};
}

var thirdClass = new thirdSampleObject();
var fourthClass = new thirdSampleObject();

thirdClass.first_var = 5;
fourthClass.first_var = 7;


console.log(thirdClass.first_var);  //returns 5
console.log(fourthClass.first_var); //returns 7

thirdSampleObject.prototype.first_var = 10;

console.log(thirdClass.first_var);  //returns 5 "protectected" within it's own instance of the object
console.log(fourthClass.first_var); //returns 7 "protectected" within it's own instance of the object

var fithClass = new thirdSampleObject();
console.log(fithClass.first_var);   //returns 3 ? Wouldn't this return 10 at this point?`
```

I would expect `console.log(fithClass.first_var)` to return 10 since I overwrote the value in the prototype. However, returns the number set in "original" prototype definition. Trying to wrap my head around why.

Comment: In the constructor you set an instance property. That property will always overshadow the property set in the prototype.

Comment: You should give your question a meaningful title, such as "property set in constructor is overriding property on prototype".

Comment: The assignment in the constructor has nothing to do with the prototype; the value of `this` in the constructor is the new object, not the prototype.

Comment: @torazaburo done. thnx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of the value of `first_var` on the prototype, your constructor explicitly sets the value on the newly created object.

The code in the constructor is doing exactly the same thing as those assignments in your code outside the constructor, in other words. Code in the constructor function is just code, and in the constructor `this` refers to the new object, not the prototype.

Comment: Got it. Hacked together a quick demo to set everyting in proper motion in my head. Much apprecaited!

Comment: @dima glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

Prototype inheritance will happen if the object doesn't have the property and the prototype of that object have the property.

```
function thirdSampleObject(){
  this.first_var = 3;
  this.update = function(){"Hi I am a function"};
}
thirdSampleObject.prototype.first_var = 10;

var fifthClass = new thirdSampleObject();  

fifthClass.hasOwnProperty('first_var'); // returns true. i,e fifthClass object have its own property 'first_var'.

console.log(fifthClass.first_var);

delete fifthClass.first_var //here we are deleting the property from object.

fifthClass.hasOwnProperty('first_var'); // returns false

console.log(fifthClass.first_var); // returns 10
```